# javascript convert dollars to egyptian pound

Tags: javascript

I have this form when the user put a number in dollar and i want to convert this number to egyptian pound

I want to use javascript to do that

```js
let dollarInput = document.querySelector("[name='dollar']");
let result = document.querySelector(".result");


dollarInput.addEventListener("input", () =>{
  if(dollarInput.value !== "" && dollarInput > 0){
     let eG = dollarInput.value * 15.6;
     result.textContent =`{${dollarInput.value}} USD Dollar = {${eG.toFixed(2)}} Egyptian Pound`;
  } 
});
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="number" name="dollar" placeholder="USD Dollar" />
  <div class="result">{0} USD Dollar = {0} Egyptian Pound</div>
</form>
```

I'm using `addEventListener` when i put a number to make a change in the div i want to print the value in dollar than en egyptian pound

but my code it's not working can anybody help me to know why and how should i do it

Comment: `dollarInput > 0` makes no sense. You’re comparing if the input _element_ is greater than 0. Please use `.valueAsNumber`, not `.value`.

Comment: In other word, change it to `&& dollarInput.value > 0` but you should be converting the value into a number before doing any comparisons

Comment: @j08691 that’s why `.valueAsNumber` has been suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be checking whether the value of the input is greater than 0, not the input element itself.

```js
let dollarInput = document.querySelector("[name='dollar']");
let result = document.querySelector(".result");


dollarInput.addEventListener("input", () =>{
  if(dollarInput.value !== "" && dollarInput.value > 0){
     let eG = dollarInput.value * 15.6;
     result.textContent =`{${dollarInput.value}} USD Dollar = {${eG.toFixed(2)}} Egyptian Pound`;
  } 
});
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="number" name="dollar" placeholder="USD Dollar" />
  <div class="result">{0} USD Dollar = {0} Egyptian Pound</div>
</form>
```

Comment: `.valueAsNumber` removes the need to parse the string.